# Pandas finding duplicated elements

Tags: python, pandas

I am running into a weird situation:

```
df.userid.size # output: 11852
df.userid.nunique() # output: 11851

df[df.duplicated(['userid']) # outputs nothing
```

Any idea on how I can find the duplicated userid?

Comment: `print(df[df.duplicated(['userid']))` -- it seems you're not running on an interactive console.

Comment: It outputs nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have one `NaN` in that column.

Demo:

```
In [24]: df
Out[24]:
     a
0  1.0
1  NaN

In [25]: df.a.nunique()
Out[25]: 1

In [26]: df.a.size
Out[26]: 2

In [27]: df.duplicated('a')
Out[27]:
0    False
1    False
dtype: bool
```